# Minimize Table Cell Height in a Display Grid in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid, card

I am developing a website that uses a grid. Just so it looks more professional and aesthetically pleasing. I want to minimize each table size where there is no open padding on the bottom of cell. I tried to create an image of what I exactly want. The red part represents content, and the open box is just the table cell.
[Here is where I am currently at (this is what I don't want).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISFe8.png) What I want is no open padding on the bottom, and every element below it moves up. [This is more of what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6WrT.png)

Here is my code.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 24px;
    color: #291F1E;
    background-color: none;
    height: auto;
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); }
}

.card {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #F7F5FA;
    color: #291F1E;
    position: relative;
    padding: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s transform;
}
```

Comment: That is not a grid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout